# storing 3 values in MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

My problem is that i have created a maths quiz that will ask the user 10 random questions and then it will output their score out of 10 at the end.I have done this art of the task but i struggle with the last part.The last part is that i need to create something that will store the last 3 scores for each user.I decided to use mysql but my code will only let me store 1 score for each user.I use python 3.4.Here is the code.

```
import random
import operator
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password',
                             host='localhost',
                             database='mydb')

cursor = cnx.cursor()


ID = input("what is your ID?")


OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "x"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

NB_QUESTIONS = 10

def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
        print("Sorry,but we need a number")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   name = input("What is your name?").title()
   Class=input("Which class do you wish to input results for 1,2 or 3?")                       
   print(name, ", Welcome to the Maths Test")

    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
        num1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num2 = random.randint(1,10)
        op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
        print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
        if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

print ("Thank you for doing this mathamatical quiz , goodbye ")


if "ID" in "Class1":
    if "score"  in "Score1":
        add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                      "(Score2)"
                      "VALUES(%s)")
        data_record = (score)


    if  "score"   in "Score2":
        add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                    "(Score3)"
                    "VALUES(%s)")
        data_record = (score)

    else:
        add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                     "(ID, Name, Score1) "
                      "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
        data_record = (ID, name, score)

cursor.execute(add_record, data_record)
cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

In my databse i have the columns ID,name,score1,score2,score3
when i complete the quiz the score,name and ID will be input into the table.But once the user with the same ID does the quiz there is a error.I want the code to store 3 scores for each user but there is a error.The error is:

cursor.execute(add_record, data_record)
NameError: name 'add_record' is not defined

Thank you for reading this and thank you also for the help.I look forward to hearing the replies.

Comment: And tag `php` here does what?

Comment: sorry id didnt mean to add that

Comment: I deleted my post because it wasn't correct. As I was saying in the comments, though. Just run this in a Python environment `"ID" in "Class1"`... It will return `False`. And so does `"score" in "Score1"` and `"score" in "Score2"`... Your problem is that **none** of your if statements are being entered. Unless you mention what you expect those lines to do, no one can help.

Comment: what i want this to do is to add a score to my database .for example i have created this peice of code that will input the user id ,name and first score to the database.But i need a peice of code that will add a second score to the user .so it will show their first score and their second score and third.I do not know how to code this.I put the if statements there because i thought that "if score1 was filled then input sccore into score2" but this did not work.

Comment: Alright. Now that I understand, forget the database for a second. Are you able to do what you just said without it?

Comment: yes i can add the user name,id and first score to the database

Comment: iv made a pice of code that willl ask the user whitch attempt it is at the quiz but i dont know how to tell the code to search for a paticular name or id to input the score into.

Comment: how can i tell mysql to search for a paticular row called the "name of user" using python code?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright, we are going to step through my solution in the smallest steps possible to reach your solution. Note: All this code in a single file works for me.

> First I create a table in the database from Python. I'm not sure why your Average column is an INT type, so I changed that. Also, my ID is an INT just for simplicity.

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password',
                             host='localhost',
                             database='mydb')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
# cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Class1")
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class1
    ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Score1 INT
    , Score2 INT
    , Score3 INT
    , Average DECIMAL(9, 5)
    );
''')
cnx.commit()
```

> Next, I create a User class in order to hold all the important information and contain the logic to go to & from the database. This way, you only require a single User object and a single method to go each way. This approach is preferred over your multiple INSERT queries.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, _id, name, score1=None, score2=None, score3=None):
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.score1 = score1
        self.score2 = score2
        self.score3 = score3

    ''' set the score of the given or next available class '''
    def add_score(self, score, Class=None):
        if not Class or (Class < 0 or Class > 3):
            if all((self.score1, self.score2, self.score3)):
                return # can't update
            elif all((self.score1, self.score2)):
                Class = 3
            elif self.score1:
                Class = 2
            else:
                Class = 1

        if Class and 0 < Class <= 3: # if a position is given and valid
            setattr(self, 'score' + str(Class), score)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return (self._id, self.name, self.score1, self.score2, self.score3)

    ''' make it possible to see this object when printed '''
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__+ str(self.to_tuple())

    ''' insert or update this user object in the database '''
    def insert_to_db(self, db):
        crsr = db.cursor()
        data = list(self.to_tuple())
        data.append(self.get_average_score())
        if User.get_by_id(self._id):
            data = data[1:]
            data.append(self._id)
            crsr.execute('''
                UPDATE Class1 SET
                    Name = %s,
                    Score1 = %s,
                    Score2 = %s,
                    Score3 = %s,
                    Average = %s
                WHERE ID = %s;
            ''', data)
        else:
            crsr.execute("INSERT INTO Class1 VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", data)
        db.commit()
        crsr.close()

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_id(_id):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Class1 WHERE ID = %s", [_id])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return User.from_tuple(row)

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_name(name):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Class1 WHERE Name = %s", [name])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return User.from_tuple(row)

    ''' Get the average score from the object. No need to query the database '''
    def get_average_score(self):
        from statistics import mean
        scores = list(self.to_tuple())[2:4]
        scores = list(filter(None.__ne__, scores))
        return mean(scores) if len(scores) > 0 else 0

    @staticmethod
    def from_tuple(tup, min_elems=2, max_elems=6):
        user = None
        if tup:
            num_elems = len(tup)
            if num_elems < min_elems or num_elems > max_elems:
                raise Exception('invalid tuple given', tup)
            # know there is at least 2 elements here
            user = User(tup[0], tup[1])
            if num_elems >= 3:
                user.score1 = tup[2]
            if num_elems >= 4:
                user.score2 = tup[3]
            if num_elems >= 5:
                user.score3 = tup[4]
        return user

    @staticmethod
    def from_cursor(cursor):
        if cursor:
            return (User.from_tuple(row) for row in cursor.fetchall())
        return iter(()) # Return empty generator if cursor == None
```

> Next, a quiz method is defined that returns the score and name of the person taking the quiz. The parameters are optional and have default values. It is a good habit to define many small methods in order to test your code and logic.

```
def quiz(num_questions=10, name=None):
    if not name:
        name = input("Enter your name: ").title()
    print(name, ", Welcome to the Maths Test")

    score = 0
    for _ in range(num_questions):
        num1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num2 = random.randint(1,10)
        op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
        print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
        if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    return name, score
```

> And finally (along with your other methods), this is the main method that will run with the program. This prompts for an ID, tries to find it in the database, then quizzes either an existing user and updates their score, or creates a new user, then inserts the user into the database.

```
def main():
    user_id = get_int_input("Enter your ID: ")
    Class = get_int_input("Which class do you wish to input results for 1, 2, or 3? ")
    user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
    if not user:
        print("User with id %d not found" % user_id)
        print("Creating new user")
        name, score = quiz(NB_QUESTIONS)
        user = User(user_id, name)
    else:
        print("Found user %s" % user.name)
        _, score = quiz(NB_QUESTIONS, user)

    user.add_score(score, Class)
    print("\nWell done", user.name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)
    print("Thank you for doing this mathamatical quiz , goodbye ")

    user.insert_to_db(cnx) # Remember to update the user in the database
    cnx.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This did not work.I recieve no error but my database did not get the second input of the score

Comment: When you do if "score" in "score1", you are testing if a string is part of another string. You could just post your full code.

Comment: what do you mean and i am realy stuck on a solution for this.

Comment: For example, "score" is **not in** "Score1" because "score" is not a substring of "Score1". Similarly "ID" is not a substring of "Class1". Those if statements shouldn't be entered at all. Is that really what you have in written in your code?

Comment: yes because i am quiet new to all of this and i am still learning .sorry.Do you know a solution?

Comment: please? is there a way i can fix this

Comment: @HarshPatel - I have written a complete answer to walk you through the solution. Let me know if you don't understand anything. Also note, that I left out `get_int_input`, `OPERATIONS`, and `NB_QUESTIONS`. You can define those above `def quiz()` if you wish.

Comment: i use mysql so do u know how to make this compatable to that?

Comment: i find sqlite very complex compared to mysql so i would realy appreciate it if u could adapt this code to work in that.

Comment: my teacher said i cant use your code for the project.I think i have a solution  i have created a if statement that will ask what attempt at the code thay are doing and accourding to that it will input their score into the diffrent colums.Do you know how to look for a paticular row in mysql.For example if bob is having a second attempt then his score will be input into the row with the name bob and in the column called score2.

Comment: @HarshPatel - Do you know SQL? `select name, score1, score2, score3 from Class1 where name='bob'` will return all rows where the name is bob. And far as I can tell, sqlite is not anymore confusing/complicated that using the [mysql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: i do not know SQL am just a kid doing a project and will my solution not work?

Comment: is it not possible for my to tell sql to look for  a name and input the score in a paticulat column?

Comment: @HarshPatel - Use an [UPDATE statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm). If you do not understand transactional database operations or basic Python syntax (completely unrelated to MySQL), then I'm afraid your teacher is asking too much of you...

Comment: do you know what code i can add to pyhton to make the database look for  a name? so the score2 and 3  can be added.if i can do this then the project is complete.

Comment: It is a multiple step process... It is not just one line. If you look at my code, I search for a user by using an id, that could easily be changed to use a name. You then need to know which score to add. You could ask the user to input a number called `course`, then do `if course == 1: ([SQL] UPDATE Class1 SET score1=score WHERE name='bob') ... elif course == 2: (UPDATE...SET score2=score...)`. Make sense?

Comment: could you adapt your code to suit mysql and make it work with my databse i have created please.id is pk in my database .

Comment: ID varchar(5) PK NN,Name varchar(10),Score1 int,Score2 int, Score3 int ,Average int

Comment: @HarshPatel - changed.

Comment: i got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HarshPatel\Desktop\Work\Computer Science\A453 Programming\test enviro\pro code.py", line 149, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\HarshPatel\Desktop\Work\Computer Science\A453 Programming\test enviro\pro code.py", line 129, in main
    user_id = get_int_input("Enter your ID: ")
NameError: name 'get_int_input' is not defined

Comment: do u know if i have to keep that and if not how do i overcome this error?

Comment: I said in my answer **along with your other methods**. You have to have that method defined (along with `OPERATIONS`, and `NB_QUESTIONS`)  in order for the code to work.

Comment: is it possible for me to adapt ur code so it works with mine? i removes the if statements that u said dont work.

Comment: if it not possible to make my code work or do i need to vastly change it to make it do what i want it to do?

Comment: I really can't help you if you don't understand each piece of the solution I shown. Here is the full code - http://pastebin.com/V9NfNfyG

Comment: This code will update the score in score 1 it does not store any values in score 2 and 3

Comment: Works for me just fine when I enter 2 for which class I want to update. I've already done your work. If something doesn't work, debug it yourself.

Comment: thanks im sorry for constant questions an still quiet new to this.I wont ask any more now :)

Comment: 1 little question.what does def from_tuple(tup, min_elems=2, max_elems=6): section of the code do.What does that whole part of the code do?

Comment: A tuple is a datatype in python. A user object requires a minimum of 2 arguments for the id and name. An additional 3 arguments are for the scores. The sixth one is the average, but the User object doesn't hold that information. Basically, it converts a row from MySQL to a python User object.

Comment: so all it does is that it allows python to understand the sql table and all of the columns ? is that what that whole section of the code do that whole part until "return user"

Comment: I wouldn't say *understand*. But, in a way, yes, it *converts* a single row from sql to a User. I think tuples are immutable (you can't change their values), so by converting it to a User object, you can freely update the fields and call additional methods like `add_score`

Comment: so that WHOLE section of the code updates and lets python understand the table?sorry could be explain to me like am an alian what tht section does

Comment: Python knows nothing about the table. *You* know the table and *you* tell python how to search for stuff from the table. That "section" (otherwise called a method) that you are referring to does no updating, it simply makes a User object from a single row in the table as I explained.

Comment: For example, these are valid tuples. `(1,'test')`, `(1,'test', 4)`, `(1,'test', 5,6,6)`. No values are looked at past 5 elements since there are only 5 fields in the User class. Any less than 2 elements are not allowed since a User **requires** both an id and a name.

Comment: i am starting to understand now

Comment: what does the _main_: do at the end?

Comment: It calls the defined main method. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 0):

if "ID" in "Class1":

```
if "score"  in "Score1":
    add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                  "(Score2)"
                  "VALUES(%s)")
    data_record = (score)

if  "score"   in "Score2":
    add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                "(Score3)"
                "VALUES(%s)")
    data_record = (score)

else:
    add_record = ("INSERT INTO Class1"
                 "(ID, Name, Score1) "
                  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    data_record = (ID, name, score)
    cursor.execute(add_record, data_record)
    cnx.commit()
```

cursor.close()
cnx.close()

Comment: This did not work.I receive no error but my database did not get the second input in the column.